# Proof of divisibility with combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Prove that, for every positive integer $\,k, {2k\choose k}\,$ is divisible by $k+1$. Hint: $\frac{2k+1}{k+1}{2k\choose k}$

What I have done so far

${2k\choose k} = 2k!/k!k!=((k+k)(k+k+1)(k+k+2)\cdots k!)/k!k!= ((k+1)(2k!/(k+1))/k!k!$

Is this proof correct or is there a better way to prove it?

Comment: The arithmetic is correct, but it does not prove the sought divisibility.

Comment: The combinatorial proof would be to take note of the Catalan numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that $\binom{2k}{k} = \frac{(k+1) (2k)! / (k+1)}{k! k!}$, but this doesn't show that $\binom{2k}{k}$ is divisible by $k+1$. You can take any number $n$ and write $n = n(k+1)/(k+1)$ even though $n$ is not divisible by $k+1$.

---

The purpose of the hint is for you to recognize that $\frac{2k+1}{k+1} \binom{2k}{k} = \binom{2k+1}{k}$ is an integer. This means $(2k+1) \binom{2k}{k}$ is divisible by $k+1$. To finish the proof, think about the common factors of $2k+1$ and $k+1$.

Comment: but when we get the equation i got won't it be the equivalent to saying it equals n(l) since the COmbination 2k!/(k+1)/k!k! is a integer

Comment: also how would i show the hint equals what you said

Comment: @user843091 How do you know $\frac{(2k)! / (k+1)}{k!k!}$ is an integer? This is exactly what the problem is asking you to show.

Comment: @user843091 Write out the definition of $\binom{2k}{k}$ and $\binom{2k+1}{k}$ and cancel terms.

Comment: I am sorry but I am still unable to find the relation could you give me a hint

Comment: @user843091 I added a proof motivated conceptually by an order viewpoint.

Answer (score 1):

It is the special case $\,n=2k\,$ below, by $\,\color{#c00}{\gcd(k\!+\!1,2k\!+\!1)= 1},\,$ by Euclid.

[Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1158286/242) $\ \ $ Both $\ \  k\!+\!1\mid {n\choose k}\ \ $ and $\ \ n\!+\!1\mid {n+1\choose k+1}\  $ when $ \ \color{#c00}{\gcd(k\!+\!1,n\!+\!1)=1}$

$\begin{align} {\bf Proof}\qquad  \dfrac{1}{k\!+\!1}\:\! \dfrac{n!}{k!(n\!-\!k)!} &\,=\, \dfrac{1}{n\!+\!1}\:\!\dfrac{(n\!+\!1)!}{(k\!+\!1)!(n\!-\!k)!}\\[.6em]
\Rightarrow\ \ \ q\, :=\, \dfrac{1}{\color{#c00}{k\!+\!1}}\ \ \ {n \choose k}\ \ \ =\!\!\!  &\qquad\!\dfrac{1}{\color{#c00}{n\!+\!1}}\,{n\!+\!1\choose k\!+\!1}
\end{align}$

[Therefore](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1197025/242)  $\,q\,$ is an integer, being a fraction writable with $\rm\color{#c00}{coprime}$ denominators.

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1165413/242) for the straightforward generalization to the non-$\rm\color{#c00}{coprime}$ case.

**Remark** $ $ *Conceptually,* the order of $\,q\,$ (= least denominator) divides coprimes so it must be $1,\,$ where the order is interpreted in the group $\,\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z = $ rationals $\!\bmod 1.\,$ Equivalently, said more simply: it is well known since grade school that the least denominator of a fraction divides every other denominator (though this is usually not *proved* till much later, e.g. by Euclid's Lemma or unique prime factorization); thus since the least denom divides coprimes it must be $1$.  The prior link gives proof(s) of this property of fractions, and elaborates on the various conceptual viewpoints emphasized above.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to prove this. Here is an algebraic one.
Start with the difference of two integers (binomial coefficients)
and end up with the Catalan number quotient:

$$ {2n \choose n}  -  {2n \choose n+1} = \tag{1}$$
$$ \frac{ (2n)! }{n!\, n!} - \frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!\,(n-1)!} = \tag{2}$$
$$ \frac{ (2n)!\,(n+1)}{n!\,(n+1)\,(n-1)!\,n} -
   \frac{ (2n)!\,n}{(n+1)!\,(n-1)!\,n} = \tag{3}$$
$$ \frac{ (2n)!}{ (n+1)!\,(n-1)!\,n} \,( (n+1)-n ) = \tag{4}$$
$$ \frac{ (2n)! }{ n!\,(n+1)\,n!}\,(1) = {2n \choose n}\frac1{n+1}. \tag{5}$$